# hide/show doesn't work in combination with jQuery address

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I'm trying to integrate jQuery address http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ into my website. As a test, I've created a test website http://electricchapel.net/ecad/. It works, but I've got one question:

I've used `hide();` to simply hide the content and I've used `show();` to show it after the content loaded. Nevertheless it slides/fades out and it slides/fades in. I don't get it. Shouldn't it simply hide and show? How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your relevant code is this:

```
$('#content').hide(function() {
    $(this).html($('#content', data).html()).show(); 
});
```

If you use `.hide()` with no arguments, then it just hides your content immediately.

If you use `.hide()` with arguments like you have, then it becomes an animation and it picks defaults for the animation parameters that are not specified which causes the type of animation you see.  Here's a generic example that shows that: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LXcDp/.

If you want immediate hide/show, you can change your code to this:

```
$('#content').hide();
$('#content').html($('#content', data).html()).show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think in your solution `$(this)` was wrong, so I simply replaced it by `$('#content')` and it worked for me.

`$('#content').hide();
$('#content').html($('#content', data).html()).show();`

+ A BIG THANK you for explaining me why `hide();` showed up as an animation.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the plugin might be overriding the hide and show functions. try hiding and showing by adding and removing a class like

```
// hide element
    $('#yourElement').addClass('hidden');

// show element
    $('#yourElement').removeClass('hidden');
```

and css:

```
.hidden{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: I've looked in the jQuery Address source code and do not see anywhere that it uses or modifies `.hide()` or `.show()` so I don't think that is correct.